# react router issue not finding main.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack

Currently, I have a react app coupled with typescript and react-router dom.

I setup up a `breadcrumbs.tsx` file like so

```
import { Link, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Breadcrumbs() {
    const location = useLocation();
    let currentLink = '';

    return (
        <ul >
            {location.pathname !== "/" ? (<li>
                <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>) : (
                <li>
                    <span>Home</span>
                </li>)
            }
            {location.pathname
                .split('/')
                .filter(crumb => crumb !== "")
                .map(crumb => {
                    currentLink += `/${crumb}`;

                    return (
                        <li key={currentLink} >
                            {"\t>>\t"}
                            {location.pathname !== currentLink ? (
                                <Link to={currentLink}>{crumb}</Link>)
                                : (
                                    <span >{crumb}</span>
                                )
                            }
                        </li>
                    );
                })
            }
        </ul>
    );
}
```

My `App.tsx` is like:

```
import Home from './Home';
import Test1 from './test1';
import Test from './test';

function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/test" element={<Test />} />
      <Route path="/test/1" element={<Test1 />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

`Home.tsx` is:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Home() {
    return (
        <div>
            <p>Home</p>
            <div><Link to="/test">test</Link></div>
            <div><Link to="/test/1">test 1</Link></div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

`Test.tsx` is:

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Breadcrumbs from "./breadcrumbs";

export default function Test() {
    return (
        <div>
            Test
            <Breadcrumbs />
            <div><Link to="/">Home</Link></div>
            <div><Link to="/test/1">test 1</Link></div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

`Test1.tsx` is same as above just with the name Test 1 and the second link goes to `/test` page.

My `webpack.common.js` build file is (NOTE: other code using scss, graphql are not shown):

```
const path = require('path');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require("css-minimizer-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.tsx',
    output: {
        filename: 'main.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
        publicPath: '/', // change to CDN in webpack.prod.js,
        assetModuleFilename: 'assets/images/[hash][ext][query]'
    },
    target: 'web',
    optimization: { // only runs in production
        minimizer: [
            `...`, // terserplugin
            new CssMinimizerPlugin()
        ]
    },
    node: {
        __dirname: true
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
                use: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            // Component / Page CSS
            {
                test: /\.module.scss$/,
                exclude: /^(?!(.*)module.scss$).*\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {
                            modules: {
                                localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
                            },
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    },
                    "sass-loader"
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.s?css$/,
                exclude: /\.module.scss$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    "css-loader",
                    "sass-loader"
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
                type: 'asset/resource'
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [
            ".js",
            ".jsx",
            ".tsx",
            ".ts",
            ".scss"
        ],
        mainFields: [
            'browser',
            'main',
            'module'
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new CopyWebpackPlugin({
            patterns: [{ from: 'public/index.html', to: 'index.html' }]
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin()
    ]
};
```

and the `prod` has additionally `mode: 'production', stats: "errors-only"`.

The `index.html` file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>App</title>
    
    <meta name="Author" content="author" />
    <meta name="Description" content="desc" />
    <meta name="Keywords" content="keyword" />

    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/logo192.png" />
    <script defer="defer" src="main.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

when I run the the application built with the webpack file shown above, and I try to route directly to `localhost:8080/test/1` (NOT using the buttons) it throws this error:

[image: picture]

Where the red lines say:

[image]

I understand the problem is because the `main.js` and `main.css` files are being built in `dist` folder, but the `html` file is looking for for them in the `/test/` folder of root directory.

How do I fix this?

Noted that: using `create-react-app my-app --template typescript` along with `react-router-dom` with the same setup, build it, and use `serve -s build`, the html file in the route `/test/1` still has the `js` and `css` files in the `/static/` folder no matter what route you are in. How do I make this happen?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem, I simply had to modify the two lines like so (Note the added `/`):

```
<script defer="defer" src="main.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
```

```
<script defer="defer" src="/main.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/main.css">
```

in the `index.html`